# If $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$, then $[A,B]=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

If two matrices $A$ and $B$ commute, then $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$ by rearrangement of the $A$'s and $B$'s in the sum. But would the converse be true?

So far I've tried to find a counterexample by considering the cases where $A$ and $B$ are 2x2 real upper triangular matrices, but those don't work.

Any hint is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You'll find a counterexample, and some further discussion, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165074/a-weak-converse-of-ab-ba-implies-eaeb-ebea-from-topics-in-matrix-analysis)

Comment: Counterexamples can also be constructed using similar matrices $A$ and $B$ such that their exponentials are scalar. I used the idea [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79905/11619), but that is somewhat unlikely to be the first appearance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The example you linked to is perfect @lulu. As an extension, what if we only want real matrices A and B?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880082/searching-two-matrix-a-and-b-such-that-expab-expaexpb-but-ab-is-not-equa) is a duplicate in which  a real counterexample is given.

Comment: If you stick with Hermitian (or if you prefer real symmetric) $A$ and $B$, then the statement is true.  The result is implied e.g. by the equality conditions of the Golden-Thompson Inequality.