# Does $e^A\ e^B=e^{A+B}$ imply $AB=BA$ for two matrices $A,B\in M_n( \mathbb{C})$?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

For two matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, if $AB=BA,$ then $e^{A+B}=e^A\ e^B$ by power series calculation. I don't know if the converse is true. Perhaps in Lie group theory can give a clear description on this question. I appreciate any idea on this problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165074/a-weak-converse-of-ab-ba-implies-eaeb-ebea-from-topics-in-matrix-analysis

Comment: See (1) [A weak converse of $AB=BA\implies e^Ae^B=e^Be^A$ from "Topics in Matrix Analysis" for matrices of algebraic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165074) (2) [If $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute, do $A$ and $B$ commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349180) (3) [If $\exp(t(A + B)) = \exp(tA) \exp(tB)$ for all $t \geq 0$ then $A,B$ commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1991471) (4) [If $|A|, |B|$ are sufficiently small, does $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$ imply that $AB = BA$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3376038)

Comment: I see, the conserve is not true in general, this is a problem deserving further thinking.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not true that $e^{A+B}=e^A e^B$ implies that $A$ and $B$ commute. There are different additional conditions that guarantee this is the case. One simple one states that if $e^{t(A+B)}=e^{tA} e^{tB}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ and $B$ commute. See

- Clément de Seguins Pazzis, On commuting Matrices and Exponentials, *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*, 2012.

for a summary of some of the results.